# ipcRenderer send vs sendSync

Tags: angular, electron

I am developing a CRUD Angular/Electron application and I would like to use [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store) to persist my data. Angular will not use directly **electron-store**. Instead it will send commands to the **ipcMain** process and the main process will save/edit/delete the data. Should I use `sendSync` or `send` from the **ipcRenderer** to communicate data to the main process?

I have read that `send` is not recommended because it is synchronous but `electron-store` does not seem to do things asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the synchronization of your operations.

`sendSync` is used when you need the function to be executed immediately or when you need a return value from this function.
It will wait for the execution of the function, as the name said is **synchronous**.

In other cases, I use `send` function, that is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! So, this is a typical CRUD application. You create an item, you edit it, you delete it. How would you approach it? AFAIU, you suggest to use sendSync for creation and deletion since I need to know the newly created item or if deletion was succesfull. Is that correct?

Comment: No, if I can I'll use the normal `send` . I mean, I create item and I send to the main.js the info.
Do you need a return value? If you need it, you have to use `sendSync` ... It totally depends from your work :)