# How to send a result to sender via contextBridge / IPCRenderer?

Tags: electron

I have a electron that looks like this

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  electronStore: {
    get(val) {
      ipcRenderer.send('electron-store-get', val);
    },
    set(property, val) {
      ipcRenderer.send('electron-store-set', property, val);
    },
    // Other method you want to add like has(), reset(), etc.
  },
});
```

and ipcMain that looks like this

```
ipcMain.on('electron-store-get', async (event, val) => {
  store.get(val);
  // console.log(reply);
  // return reply;
  // event.reply('electron-store-get', reply);
});
ipcMain.on('electron-store-set', async (event, property, val) => {
  // console.log(val);
  store.set(property, val);
});
```

When I was trying to call the function via electron.electronStore.get(), it returns undefined

```
let a = window.electron.electronStore.get('test');
console.log(a);
```

However, I've tested that on the line of ipcRenderer.send(""), I was able to receive data by setting as below

```
let result = ipcRenderer.send('electron-store-get',val);
console.log(result);
```

Which mean, ipcRenderer is not undefined and set has been successfuly, get as-well, just it went missing when i invoke the ipcMain Get functions

Comment: your `get` function doesn't actually return any value. Either use `sendSync` and then do `e.returnValue = store.get(val)` in your main script or use `return ipcRenderer.invoke("electron-store-get", val)` in preload and `ipcMain.handle(...` and have the handler return the value. Your `get` function however will become `async` if you do this and you will need to await the result

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904715/ipcrenderer-send-vs-sendsync) though not necessarily a dupe

Comment: Hi, manage to get it working, perhaps you can add it as an answer so I can mark this as answeered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current preload API isn't actually returning anything:

```
get(val) {
   ipcRenderer.send('electron-store-get', val);
}
```

You'll want to either use the synchronous API: `return ipcRenderer.sendSync('electron-store-get', val)` and then have your handler in main do:

```
ipcMain.on('electron-store-get', (event, val) => {
  event.returnValue = store.get(val);
});
```

Or make the preload API async:

```
get(val) {
   return ipcRenderer.invoke('electron-store-get', val);
}
```

```
ipcMain.handle('electron-store-get', (event, val) => {
  return store.get(val);
});
```

And then:

```
let a = await window.electron.electronStore.get('test');
```